# Android Java - withdraw money output?

Tags: java, android

In my Java Program I have a method:

```
private void giveMoney(int money) {
    int notes[] = {10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500};
    StringBuffer cash = new StringBuffer();
    int i = notes.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0)
        if (notes[i] > money)
            i--;
        else {
            cash.append(notes[i]).append(" ");
            money -= notes[i];
        }
    System.out.print(cash);
}
```

For, example, if 
money == 990
the output will be: 500 200 200 50 20 20

I want to work out how to calculate how the cash will be dispensed using the following notes: 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10.

Comment: The cash should be dispensed using all notes: 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question correct, this is the line you want:

```
int amount = (int) Math.floor(money/banknotes[i]);
```

The whole function:

```
private void giveCash(int money) {
    int banknotes[] = {10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500};
    StringBuffer cash = new StringBuffer();
    int i = banknotes.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        if (banknotes[i] > money) {
            i--;
        } else {
            int amount = (int) Math.floor(money/banknotes[i]);
            cash.append(banknotes[i]).append("x").append(amount).append(" ");
            money -= banknotes[i]*amount;
        }
    }
    TextView tvCash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cash);
    tvCash.setText(cash);
}
```

Output:

```
500x1 200x2 50x1 20x2
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically get an int count of how many times each note goes into an adjusted total. i.e. you adjust the total to remove any value of that has been dispensed with larger notes.
Using modulus you get the remainder that is not divisible by that note and pass that value as the adjusted value to test for how many notes can be dispensed in that denomination.

I've given you the algorithm.

```
500_amounts = (int) amount/500

500_Leftover = amount % 500

200_amounts = (imt) 500_Leftover/200

200_Leftover = 500_Leftover % 200

100_amount = (int) 200_Leftover/100

100_Leftover = 200_Leftover % 100

// and so on
```

***Note this is pseudo code and you cannot name your variable like this, nor will it run like this.***

I should add for best practices it's best to use constants for the values of the denominations and as suggested in the other answer, as it is not explicit here, it would be good to loop through these.